# Mixing two different script

Tags: jquery

I have here two different jquery. A form validation and script for changing the value of rfq and bid textbox depends in the value of dropdown select. My 2nd script function when my dropdown select for example bidding, the bid textbox showing and the rfq textbox is hiding and it's value is clear. Just like if I select rfq the rfq textbox comes out and bid textbox is hiding and it's value becomes clear. The problem is when I try to submit, the form validation comes out bcoz the rfq or bid textbox value is none.

Here's my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mHCk7/

What I need is mix my 2nd script to my 1st script to function my validation correctly.

Help please?

**1st Script**

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var validation_holder;

    $("form#register_form input[name='submit']").click(function() {

    var validation_holder = 0;
//  /^[A-Za-z\s]+$/


        var rfq         = $("form#register_form input[name='n_rfq']").val();
        var rfq_regex   = /^[0-9\-]+$/; // reg ex qty check
        var bid             = $("form#register_form input[name='n_bid']").val();
        var bid_regex   = /^[0-9\-]+$/; // reg ex qty check
        var mode                = $("form#register_form select[name='n_mode']").val();
        var mode_regex      =  /^[a-zA-Z ]+$/; // reg ex qty check

        /* validation start */  

        if(bid == "") {
            $("span.val_bid").html("This field is required.").addClass('validate');
            validation_holder = 1;
        } else {
            if(!bid_regex.test(bid)){ // if invalid phone
                $("span.val_bid").html("Integer Only is Allowed!").addClass('validate');
                validation_holder = 1;

            } else {
                $("span.val_bid").html("");
            }
        }

        if(rfq == "") {
            $("span.val_rfq").html("This field is required.").addClass('validate');
            validation_holder = 1;
        } else {
            if(!rfq_regex.test(rfq)){ // if invalid phone
                $("span.val_rfq").html("Integer Only is Allowed!").addClass('validate');
                validation_holder = 1;

            } else {
                $("span.val_rfq").html("");
            }
        }

        if(mode == "") {
            $("span.val_mode").html("This field is Required.").addClass('validate');
            validation_holder = 1;
        } else {
            if(!mode_regex.test(mode)){ // if invalid phone
                $("span.val_mode").html("Invalid Special Characters!").addClass('validate');
                validation_holder = 1;

            } else {
                $("span.val_mode").html("");
            }
        }           

        if(validation_holder == 1) { // if have a field is blank, return false
            $("p.validate_msg").slideDown("fast");
            return false;
        }  validation_holder = 0; // else return true
        /* validation end */    
    }); // click end 

}); // jQuery End
```

**2nd Script**

```
$('#txt1').change(function () {
if ($(this).val() == 'NEGOTIATED' || $(this).val() == 'SHOPPING' || $(this).val() == '') {
    $("#txt2,#txt3").val('');
}
else if ($(this).val() == 'BIDDING') {
    $("#txt3").val('');
}
else if ($(this).val() == 'RFQ') {
    $("#txt2").val('');
}
else {
    //here you can specify what to do if the value is NOT negotiated or SHOPPING
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

/** Change like this **/

/* In the page text box control add class name as mandatory*/

```
 if(bid.hasClass("mandatory")) {
        $("span.val_bid").html("This field is required.").addClass('validate');
        validation_holder = 1;
    } else {
        if(!bid_regex.test(bid)){ // if invalid phone
            $("span.val_bid").html("Integer Only is Allowed!").addClass('validate');
            validation_holder = 1;

        } else {
            $("span.val_bid").html("");
        }
    }

    if(rfq.hasClass("mandatory")) {
        $("span.val_rfq").html("This field is required.").addClass('validate');
        validation_holder = 1;
    } else {
        if(!rfq_regex.test(rfq)){ // if invalid phone
            $("span.val_rfq").html("Integer Only is Allowed!").addClass('validate');
            validation_holder = 1;

        } else {
            $("span.val_rfq").html("");
        }
    }
```

/** 2nd Script **/

```
$('#txt1').change(function () {
if ($(this).val() == 'NEGOTIATED' || $(this).val() == 'SHOPPING' || $(this).val() == '') {
    $("#txt2,#txt3").val('');
    $("#txt2").removeClass("mandatory");
    $("#txt3").removeClass("mandatory");
}
else if ($(this).val() == 'BIDDING') {
    $("#txt3").val('');
    $("#txt3").removeClass("mandatory");
}
else if ($(this).val() == 'RFQ') {
    $("#txt2").val('');
    $("#txt2").removeClass("mandatory");
}
else {
    //here you can specify what to do if the value is NOT negotiated or SHOPPING
}
});
```

Comment: can try it into fiddle? I tried it but it's not working